# Is it possible to use a Document class that is above the FLA in the directory structure?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

Is it possible to use a Document class that is above the FLA in the directory structure?

If so, please explain how.

This is how I currently have my directory structure:

```
[d] site
 │
 ├─[d] as3
 |  |
 |  ├─ Site.as        //Document class for site.fla
 |  ├─ SectionA.as    //Document class for section_a.fla
 |  └─ SectionB.as    //Document class for section_b.fla
 |    
 ├─ site.fla
 ├─ section_a.fla
 └─ section_b.fla
```

I'd like to do this:

```
[d] site
 │
 ├─[d] as3
 |  |
 |  ├─ Site.as        //Document class for site.fla
 |  ├─ SectionA.as    //Document class for section_a.fla
 |  └─ SectionB.as    //Document class for section_b.fla
 | 
 ├─[d] swf
 |  |
 |  ├─ section_a.fla //Document class for this is above it in the directory structure
 |  └─ section_b.fla //Document class for this is above it in the directory structure
 |
 └─ site.fla
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible. You just need to add the directory to your class-paths list in your Fla.

(on PC) Go to `File > Publish Settings`.

Then click the *Settings* button beside the `ActionScript version` dropdown.

Add your class directories by clicking the little `plus sign` (+) button. You can manually type the relative path, or click the little `target` button to browse for the directory. In you case you can just manually enter - `./as3/` as your class path

Just a note. It is best practice to put your classes in a sub-directory, but this directory is usually called `src`. And usually you publish your SWF(s) to a directory called `bin`.

Comment: Thank-you for pointing out best practice. After I read your answer, I found this link http://www.warmforestflash.com/blog/2009/10/folder-structure-and-project-organization-best-practices/ and have restructured my site. It is much more manageable now.